# How to fill empty lines in an Excel file ummerged in php?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have this code that allows me to read an xlsx file containing merged celles and unmerged them to be able to process them.
The xlsx unmerged file is like this :
[image]

And I would like the empty lines to be filled like this:
[image]

Each time the 'Style' value changes the empty cells are filled with the values of the lines above.
I tried with `foreach($sheet->getMergeCells() as $cells){ $sheet->setCellValue($cells);}` but it doesn't work .

How do I solve my problem?

```
<?php

//uploaded xlsx file recovery
$xlsx="C:/wamp64/www/Extract_pictures_Excel/xlsx_files/".date('Y_m_d H-i-s')."_file.xlsx";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mon_fichier"]["tmp_name"],$xlsx);

require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($xlsx);

//reading the xlsx file
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
echo 'before unmerge: ', count($sheet->getMergeCells()), PHP_EOL;

    foreach($sheet->getMergeCells() as $cells)
        {
            
            $sheet->unmergeCells($cells);
            foreach($sheet->getMergeCells() as $cells)
            {
                $sheet->setCellValue($cells);
            }
        }

echo 'after unmerge: ', count($sheet->getMergeCells()), PHP_EOL;

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
$objWriter->save('./unmerged_files/unmerged.xlsx');

?>
```

Comment: Use this PseudoCode(!) `foreach($sheet->getMergeCells() as $range) {
    $value = getValueFromRange($range);
    $sheet->unmergeCells($range);
    foreach($range as $cell) $sheet->setCellValue($cell, $value); 
}
` That is no real code, but a algorithm what to do.

Comment: I changed the code with the syntax of the documentation but for the second foreach I have: 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'. I used `$value = $sheet->rangeToArray($range);`

Comment: It returns a two-dimensional array! You need to read the docs carefully, please. To get it use `$value = $sheet->rangeToArray($range)[0][0];` for example.

Comment: Ok thank I modify that, in the documentation it is used with hard cells for example 'C3:E5', I had not understood well. But my problem persists...

Comment: You should use a debugger to understand what happens.

Comment: I'm going to watch this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value of the first cell of the range. Because it is a 2-dimensional array, we can get the first element via `[0][0]`.

Then we get all cells and most important, the CellReference by setting last param to true. This will make the 2-dimensional array having first being row keys and seconds being column keys.

Having that data and the value, we can unmerge the cells and set all the cells in the range with the same value.

```
$row = 0;
$skipRows = [1, 3];
foreach($sheet->getMergeCells() as $range) {
    $value = $sheet->rangeToArray($range)[0][0];
    $cells = $sheet->rangeToArray($range, null, true, true, true);
    $sheet->unmergeCells($range);
    if(in_array(++$row, $skipRows)) continue;
    if(!$value) continue;

    foreach($cells as $row => $columns) {
        foreach(array_keys($columns) as $column) {
            $sheet->setCellValue("$column$row", $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your precise explanations, it works perfectly! Just a little detail, since the header was in a merged cell it copies itself on all the first cells of my xlsx file like this: http://upload.ripcurl-europe.com/dld.php?i=01d8d4c5-515d-4e0d-b1c3-2bc884d0e3f3  same for the date at the very end

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much the first lines remain unchanged now. I've just seen that at the end of the file the date is also duplicated, but it's going to be more complicated to ignore it, isn't it?

Comment: Sure, just compare if it contains 'data as of'.

Comment: Perfect, I added this modification and it works perfectly!